# Effective user id, 0, must match the owner of QMCONFIG, 0

Tags: bea, tuxedo

I've installed Tuxedo 12c 64 bits in a Windows Server 2012. But when I execute the command "qmadmin" the console raise the next error:

ERROR: Effective user id, 0, must match the owner of QMCONFIG, 0.

I use the same user that I used to install Tuxedo.

Anybody knows why this error is raised?

Comment: Very quickly putting the error message into a search engine gets you to (amongst others) https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26665_01/tuxedo/docs11gr1/messages/q/q011.html

Comment: The doc says the following: "Change the ownership of the QMCONFIG device or file, or run the program as the corresponding user" But as I said before, I use the same user that I used to install Tuxedo.